# Why org.json.JSONObject getLong and getString not equal

Tags: android, json, org.json

Code like this:

```
     JSONObject contentObject = new JSONObject(content);
     JSONObject params = contentObject.getJSONObject("response_params");
     Log.d("onTest", "channel_id:" + params.getString("channel_id"));
     Log.d("onTest", "channel_id:" + params.getLong("channel_id"));
```

Log print:

```
   08-21 12:46:21.470: DEBUG/onTest(25228): onMessage: content : {"response_params":{"appid":"1071410","channel_id":"3537275240990320342","user_id":"714893193627619861"},"request_id":1293438498}
   08-21 12:46:21.480: DEBUG/onTest(25228): channel_id:3537275240990320342
   08-21 12:46:21.480: DEBUG/onTest(25228): channel_id:3537275240990320128
```

Why getLong with value 3537275240990320128,but get String with value 3537275240990320342?

Comment: Can you show what actually content is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getLong%28java.lang.String%29),

```
public long getLong (String name)
```

> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a long or can be
>   coerced to a long. Note that JSON represents numbers as doubles, so
>   this is lossy; use strings to transfer numbers via JSON.

**EDIT:**
To see it yourself you can do this

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {
    json.put("test", "3537275240990320342");
    String str = json.getString("test");
    double dou = Double.parseDouble(str);
    long lo = (long) dou;
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You will see that the value of `lo` is exactly what you are getting when you do `getLong`

Comment: @keepcleargas I think, this is the correct reason behind the values you are receiving.

Comment: hmmm...its gud answer...:)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple...your JSON contains value of `channel_id` as string type...if you are sure that you have `channel_id` is of type long...**remove double quotes** form value of `channel_id`.

Yur new JSON will look like,

```
{
    "response_params":
        {
            "appid":"1071410",
            "channel_id":3537275240990320342, // here
            "user_id":"714893193627619861"
        },
    "request_id":1293438498
 }
```

Have a look at these [examples](http://json.org/example.html).

hope this helps....

Comment: @umair.ali: you won't be able to do what you have suggested above, because the value is too big for an `int`. You will need to convert it to a `double` before you can use it in JSON (for reasons already mentioned in the documentation). That's why passing it as a `String` is recommended.

Comment: @Rajeev: this might be larger than int...but not long, as max value for long is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: yes, but wherever you are forming the `JSON`, you will need to use a trailing `L` to let the compiler know that it is a `long`, else the compiler will try to interpret it as `int` only. So in my example above i will need to use `json.put("test", 3537275240990320342L);`